# Can I really return a reactive variable and have it update its value asynchronosly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When reading the code of a frontend written in Vue3 I stumbled upon a construction I have not seen so far and I have some problems understanding how it works. The basic idea is assigning to a reactive value the result of an asynchronous call (the JSON result of a `fetch` for instance).

The way I have been doing it is shown in the code below ([Vue Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UMtOw0AM/BVrL9lI6aZwLGklxA9w4LiXENw2Vfah9SYVivLveDdQEEjcPPZ47JlZPHqvphHFTjTUhd5HIIyjP2jbG+9ChBkCHmGBY3AGCqYW2mrbOUsRDJ1gn+aycBaL8nvS0rvtntph4LksYX8Ai1d4Zo2eUMqA5IYJK969YBczYdYW0vGX3qAbo1zXcheYlxekFvHqtCgfUnup4H673Saw5Nu3q7JU8YxWhiTBX6qpHUZMv2ZeU69e2SWDiMYPbURGAM357jDP2dmyNDWjRL9RRCXWXDam9epCznJy+Uf9OSAtdl9fa8F5JazFOUZPu7qmY5fyvpBy4VRzpcJoI1tWSGbzGtyVMLCwFtUPjZqbE4ZNQPuGAcN/mr+of3RzcpyYWD4AxD+s5A==)). The `setTimeout` simulates the asynchronous call, a Promise is returned, and then acted upon via a `then()` that sets the reactive variable `msg`.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('one')

const asyncCall = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("two");
  }, 2000);
})

asyncCall().then(r => msg.value = r)

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

---

The code I stumbled upon ([Vue Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UMtug0AM/BVrLxApgbTHiESq+gs97oVSkxCxD9kLaYX493qB0KiVelvbM7MzM6gX77O+Q3VQBVfU+ACMofMnbRvjHQUYgLCGEWpyBhKBJtpqWznLAQyf4RjvafKZbH72JX/Z6rVsW7mmGzieYNAWYD4ScteGO89ZjEyI3741Bl0X0gcKLPCsL9sOhZSEmxMHAOMWnvf7/cQlsUx2gWo7RifibSWtftLJZJHPUSWkDAGNb8uAMgEUl6fTMEzBxrHIZYrwFaK2aq5lZ0qfXdlZKW4yqpcDa3W4W9dK6oqzVpcQPB/ynOsq1n3lzNE5l1dGnQ2SO0M2u3dyN0YSYa22Dxq5LHukHaH9QEL6T/MX9I/u1J10pMZvOPqtxA==)) takes a different approach: it creates a **local** reactive variable in a function, makes the asynchronous call and when it resolves it sets the value of that local ref variable. It is then returned (this is the visual sequence, the execution is different, see comments further down)

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('x')

const asyncCall = () => {
  const result = ref('one')
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.value = 'two'
  }, 2000)
  return result
}

msg.value = asyncCall()

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

It works as well, but I do not understand:

- ... why the local variable `result` is updated once we leave `asyncCall` (and return `result` with its default value of `one` because the callback in `setTimeout()` has not happened yet). It should be destroyed once the function is over.
- ... why I can return `result` (a pointer) and assign it to `msg.value` (a string) (and it works)
- <del>... why the displayed value (`"one"` and `"two"`) have quotes.</del> converted to [its own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74129879/why-are-quotes-displayed-around-a-ref-string).

**My question: is the second approach correct? recommended? It surely simplifies code because all the asynchronous part happens in the function, but I have never seen that approach.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call an `async` function is not, technically, an `async` function. It's a function returning a `ref()`. *Immediately*, without any asynchrony.

But that function also has a side effect (the `setTimeout`). At some point in the future, it updates the returned `ref`. Because you're assigning the result to another `ref`, when you modify the returned one's value you actually modify the value of the one it was assigned to.

To your point, it's perfectly legal. You can assign `ref()`s to a `reactive()`'s prop or to another `ref()` and if/when you update the returned `ref`'s value, the one you passed it to will also update.

---

To make my point clearer, in the example you linked, `msg.value` starts off as `x`, it's immediately assigned the value of `ref('one')` and two seconds later the inner `ref()`'s value is changed to `'two'`.
After this assignment, if you check `msg.value`, it is a `ref()`, it's no longer a `string`. But that's not a problem for `<template>` because it automatically unwraps any nested refs, until it gets to the actual `.value`.
However, be weary of using `msg.value` inside the controller (after the assignment), as you will have to `unref` it to get to the `string` value.

Another potential problem one might encounter with this technique is `watch`-ing `msg` will no longer detect changes after the assignment, because its value remains the same: `result`. To get past this problem, one would need to use `{ deep: true }` in the watcher's options.

Comment: *it updates the returned `ref`* - this is the key part I was missing for the first "why", thanks. If I understand correctly, `setTimeout` still has a grip on the pointer despite the function being closed and its local variables vanished.

Comment: I tried to use "asynchronous" instead of `async` to avoid mixing up the fact that "things happen sometime, when they happen" and the keyword `async`.

Comment: I need to insist: The function's name is misleading. It should be named:  "`iAmNotAsync`". It's not a promise, it's not pending, it returns immediately... something. That something happens to be a `ref()` which, just like any other `ref` can be modified, which is exactly what `setTimeout` does, but the returned result has no knowledge of this future update. We call async behavior anything returning a a promise, which announces (promises) a `resolve` or `reject` at some future point. Until that point, it's in a state of pending.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, thank you for following-up. A Promise is also returned immediately, and then something happens and it is addressed again. In my case the function immediately returns a `ref()`, and it is, as you are saying, updated after some time. From a pure sequencing perspective, these "things that happen sometime" are outside the main sequence of the program - thus my use of "asynchronous". Now, if JS has a specific meaning for "asynchronous" I will of course use the correct/proper verbiage (but then I am not sure how to describe what my function does)

Comment: You say: *"despite the function being closed and its local variables vanished"*. That's not true. They are not destroyed/garbage collected unless they are no longer referenced. But yours is referenced, inside the `setTimeout`. It's a classic [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) example.

Comment: *It's a classic closure example* Thank you - I learned something today :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you find my answer confusing or using concepts which, at this point in time do not have a clear definition for you, going through [Asynchronous Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) might clarify terms a bit.

Comment: Your answer is not confusing at all. I am an amateur dev for 30 years (some 10 years of amateur JS) and I just want to speak the right language. Answers such as yours - clear and concise - are great. I will split the other "why"s into separate questions

Comment: Ah, you answered to the second "why" while I was dispatching it to its own question! (thank you) Would you mind moving it there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74129830/why-can-i-successfully-assign-a-ref-to-a-string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248911/discussion-between-tao-and-woj).