# Why are quotes displayed around a ref() string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Consider the following code, where a string is displayed,the content of a `ref()`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('x')

const asyncCall = () => {
  const result = ref('one')
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.value = 'two'
  }, 2000)
  return result
}

msg.value = asyncCall()

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

**Why does the displayed value (`"one"` and `"two"`) have quotes?**

Below is an animated screenshot that shows (after I reload the window) how `"one"` turns into `"two"`

[image]

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in vue, but it seems odd to set the value of one ref to another ref. It seems like that's where the quotes come from. Just setting `msg = asyncCall()` instead of `msg.value` seems to fix it. But no idea what I'm really doing in vue, so take that for what its worth.

Comment: @CollinD: as for the assignment, this is actually a "dispatched question" from [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128172/can-i-really-return-a-reactive-variable-and-have-it-update-its-value-asynchronos).

Comment: Replacing `msg` with the `ref()` returned by the function does fix the problem as @CollinD suggests. Although we'd need to use `let` instead of `const` when declaring `msg`, to be able to reassign it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return `.value` when you return the `result` to get rid off the issue :

```js
 return result.value
```

However this works fine but I prefer to use a Vue way such as computed property or watch :

```html
<script setup>
import { ref , watch} from 'vue'

const msg = ref('x ')
 const result = ref('one')

const asyncCall = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    result.value = 'two'
  }, 2000)
 
}
asyncCall()

watch(result,(v)=>{
  console.log(v)
  msg.value=result.value
},{
  immediate:true
})
  
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain objects and arrays are not unwrapped in templates. for example:

```
import {computed, ref} from "vue"

const arr1 = [
  computed(()=> "some thing"),
]

const arr2 = ref([
  computed(()=> "some thing"),
])
//Both, arr1[0] and arr2[0] will get "some thing", with quotes.
```

to get the computed value:

```
{{ arr1[0].value }}
```

currently [vue 3.4], you print the whole computed object, which will be run through JSON.stringify(), so you end up with the quotes.

- Short answer:

```
return.value
```

##### Links:

- Related github issue: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5519
- Vue reactivity: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#stateful-methods

Comment: That's actually [not true](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kTFPwzAQhf+K5SUgVY0QTFWoBKgDDICA0UuaXtIUx7bsc4kU+b9zdpSQAXXzfe/d+Z1u4A/GrM8e+IYXrrKtQeYAvdkK1XZGW2QDs1CzwGqrO5aRNROq0sohq7Vm91G9yvalza4nvp85OYgW+TiZZlKB0BlZIlDFWHG82Q5DmhRCkVO1oHHOTIt80chXHB19VrfN+uS0ovRDbBS80p1pJdg3gy2FEXzDkhK1Ukr985IYWg+riVdHqL7/4SfXRyb4uwUH9gyCzxqWtgEc5d3nK/T0nsVOH7wk9wXxA5yWPmYcbY9eHSj2wpfSPqcbtKr5crseQblpqRg0OkPyC053ebqw+l/c2/Vd6hMq8PALnOCodQ==). The behavior only happens if the assignment is done after mounting the component. Would you care to explain why?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35735449)